# What is the 35mm film equivalent of the HQ camera lenses?

Tags: camera

The official "HQ" camera offered by the Raspberry Pi corporation is able to mount different lenses, and [they recommend](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#ccs-lenses) a 6mm wide angle and a 16mm telephoto lens option.

But of course back in the days of a 35mm (film size) SLR camera a lens with a 16mm focal length would no way be a "telephoto" lens! If I understand correctly, the reason that 16mm can be a telephoto in this case is because the sensor size is so much smaller too.

What would be the conversion factor for these lenses to get the old equivalent — is the 16mm lens on the HQ camera more like a traditional SLR 100mm telephoto or a 400mm telephoto or what sort of "zoom" should I expect? Can I multiply the 16mm of this lens/sensor combo by some number to get a 35mm film equivalent of the focal length?

Comment: your question belongs at https://photo.stackexchange.com/ because the answer is dependent on knowledge of SLR cameras and lenses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Pi camera sensor is much smaller. According to this [manual](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/raspberry-pi-hq-camera-lenses.pdf), the HQ camera sensor is 6.3 x 4.7 mm. That's 5.7 times smaller (in terms of linear dimensions) than the 35mm film.

Multiplying 16mm by 5.7 gives you about 90mm, pretty close to the 100mm equivalent for a film camera. You'll get some zoom with it, but nothing close to a 400mm telephoto lens.

Comment: Thanks, also checks out for the 6mm lens — would be ~34mm lens in traditional consumer film format which is certainly not in fisheye territory but still relatively wide!